# Forcing tens deciminal place value in tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to display the value `0.5` in a tikz node but the MWE below keeps displaying `0`. I've googled everything; how do I make this work!?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]

  \begin{scope}[xscale=15/4,yscale=5/60]

    \foreach \ee [remember=\b as \b (initially 0), ] in{0,...,4}{
      \ifnum\ee=0 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\b}{0.5} \fi %<----- Fix this, make it show 0.5
      \ifnum\ee=1 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\b}{5} \fi
      \ifnum\ee=2 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\b}{50} \fi
      \ifnum\ee=3 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\b}{500} \fi
      \ifnum\ee=4 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\b}{5000} \fi
      \draw (\ee,0)node[anchor=south]{\pgfmathprintnumber{\b}};
    }

  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\pgfmathsetmacro` for real (floating point) numbers. the `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` is for intrgers and this is your mistake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\pgfmathtruncatemacro` is a pgf function that stores integer values.

The alternative for real numbers and not only integers the command is : `\pgfmathsetmacro`

This way your example becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]

  \begin{scope}[xscale=15/4,yscale=5/60]

    \foreach \ee [remember=\b as \b (initially 0), ] in{0,...,4}{
      \ifnum\ee=0 \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{0.5} \fi %<----- Fix this, make it show 0.5 %Changed only here!!!
      \ifnum\ee=1 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\b}{5} \fi
      \ifnum\ee=2 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\b}{50} \fi
      \ifnum\ee=3 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\b}{500} \fi
      \ifnum\ee=4 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\b}{5000} \fi
      \draw (\ee,0)node[anchor=south]{\pgfmathprintnumber{\b}};
    }

  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\pgfmathsetmacro` is not for floating point. For that, you'd need to load the relevant library and activate the relevant option. Really, what the truncation macro does is truncate things, whereas `\pgfmathsetmacro` doesn't.

Comment: @cfr what do you mean? I mean that `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` accepts only integers and you have to use `\pgfmathsetmacro` if the value is not integer... Are my English the mistake? is a floating poind something different than a real non integer number?

Comment: @cfr.. Thanks... Found the difference between floating point and real numbers... I will rephrase... (Didn't knew that latex have a library for that reason)

Comment: Really, I don't think it is that the truncation one can only store integers - otherwise, you'd get an error. It is that it actively truncates them. But it is true that it stores only the integer part of whatever you give it.

Answer (score 5):

Note that you could more simply make `\ee` a count of the cycles and specify `\b`. For example,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
  \begin{scope}[xscale=15/4,yscale=5/60]
    \foreach \b [count=\ee from 0] in {0.5,5,50,500,5000}{
      \draw (\ee,0) node[anchor=mid] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\b}};
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: numbers]

I don't know whether this is useful or not, as your real example is doubtless more complex. However, handling each value with an `\ifnum ... \fi` is, in any case, probably a tedious way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for simplifying the /foreach. I've used this solution in my code.